# Create a list from excel columns using pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have downloaded an Excel file from Google Docs https://drive.google.com/file/d/15UPaF2xJLSVz8DYuphierz67trCxFLcl/view and I would like to create two lists. One with the words from the negative sheet and one with the words from the constraining sheet.
So far I have the following code:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
workbook = load_workbook(filename="list.xlsx")
workbook.sheetnames

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('list.xlsx', sheet_name=['Negative','Constraining'], header=None, names=None, index_col=None, squeeze=True)
df
```

This gives me the following output:

```
OrderedDict([('Negative', 0            ABANDON
              1          ABANDONED
              2         ABANDONING
              3        ABANDONMENT
              4       ABANDONMENTS
                          ...     
              2350      WRONGDOING
              2351     WRONGDOINGS
              2352        WRONGFUL
              2353      WRONGFULLY
              2354         WRONGLY
              Name: 0, Length: 2355, dtype: object),
             ('Constraining', 0               ABIDE
              1             ABIDING
              2               BOUND
              3             BOUNDED
              4              COMMIT
                          ...      
              179          STRICTER
              180         STRICTEST
              181          STRICTLY
              182    UNAVAILABILITY
              183       UNAVAILABLE
              Name: 0, Length: 184, dtype: object)])
```

I have then tried to change the OrderedDict into a DataFrame using this code:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df, index=[0])
df1
```

And receive this output:

```
   Negative Constraining
0   ABANDON ABIDE
```

If I enter a different number in the index column, I get a different word from the lists. If I remove index completely, then I get an error. 
The parameters I have added into `df = pd.read_excel()` have come from trial and error and reading the documentation. I'm not sure if these are right.

I'd appreciate any help. I am new to this, so I don't always understand the more sophisticated solutions. Thank You.

Comment: `df` is an orderedDict since you have multiple sheets, the get a DataFrame you must query your orderedDict object by doing `df1  = df['Negative']`

Comment: What you have is a dictionary of dataframes or series. You don't need to make it a dataframe, you need to index into it to get the DFs. `df['Negative']` is a dataframe (or series), and `df['Constraining']` is a dataframe (or series)

Comment: Thank you both. It's always the simple things that I struggle with